# Flutter: How to add shadow to transparent container?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

[image]

I want to have a shadow only on the edge of the transparent container as you can see in the navigation bar at the top [Picture 1]. Boxshadow doesn't work in this case, because you see the whole shadow behind the transparent widget. Is there a way to only add shadow from the edge on?

I appreciate your help

Comment: so you want a shadow on four edges of your container? or only one edge? is it to be an inner or outer shadow?

Comment: an outer shadow at the bottom side of the container shadow. It should be like an normal looking shadow that starts at the edge of the container, because the normal boxshadow is also behind the container which makes it ugly for a transparent container.

Comment: thank you pskink^^Thats what I looked for. You solved my problem. Can you write your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this custom `Decoration` (you can add some other parameters like background color, gradient etc if you want):

```
class FooDecoration extends Decoration {
  final EdgeInsets insets;
  final Color color;
  final double blurRadius;
  final bool inner;

  FooDecoration({
    this.insets = const EdgeInsets.all(12) ,
    this.color = Colors.black,
    this.blurRadius = 8,
    this.inner = false,
  });
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([void Function() onChanged]) => _FooBoxPainter(insets, color, blurRadius, inner);
}

class _FooBoxPainter extends BoxPainter {
  final EdgeInsets insets;
  final Color color;
  final double blurRadius;
  final bool inner;

  _FooBoxPainter(this.insets, this.color, this.blurRadius, this.inner);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    var rect = offset & configuration.size;
    canvas.clipRect(rect);
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.outer, blurRadius);

    var path = Path();
    if (inner) {
      path
        ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
        ..addRect(insets.inflateRect(rect))
        ..addRect(rect);
    } else {
      path.addRect(insets.deflateRect(rect));
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
}
```

sample usage (notice that all params have some default values):

```
child: Container(
  color: Colors.grey[200],
  child: Container(
    decoration: FooDecoration(
      insets: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
      // color: Colors.black,
      // blurRadius: 8,
      // inner: true,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to figure out how we can use a clipper to clip the inside of the container in order to get rid of the shadow color.

**Here's my solution**:

First things first, I've created an `InvertedClipper` whose task is to clip the inside of a widget:

```
class InvertedClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {


InvertedClipper();

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path.combine(
      PathOperation.difference,
      Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height)),
      Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(1, 1, size.width - 5, size.height - 5)),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

For this, I've followed [this interesting article](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/how-to-cut-a-hole-in-an-overlay/2020/510/).

That said, I tried the clipper right away but noticed that if you clip a `Container` with a shadow, the shadow loses the `spread` and `blur`.

Googling about it I've stumbled upon the package [clip_shadow](https://pub.dev/packages/clip_shadow) which allows to add a shadow to a clipped widget (which is what you need).

Following the readme I did this:

```
class DummyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Center(
        child: ClipShadow(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black,
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 7,
              offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
          clipper: InvertedClipper(),
          child: Container(
            height: 250,
            width: 250,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That led to this result:
[image: clip shadow result]

Sorry for the enormous image, I don't know how to size it in Markdown. Other than that I hope this helped.

Happy coding!

Comment: thank you magiclean94 for your engagement :) is it possible to make the the beginning of the shadow sharp (no blur?) and just going into blur along the way? Do you know what I mean as I refer to my picture? Be cuse with that  method the beginning and the end of the shadow are blur.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're asking... I mean I can't figure out what you're referring to in the picture. You can have different shadows with different offset, blur and spread each, since `boxShadow` is a `List<BoxShadow>`, so you might have different BoxShadows with different values orchestrated in order to give the desired result. I'm not sure I've answered to your question though

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround you could set the container's color to its background's color. Then you can use BoxShadow.

Comment: the backround is dynamic