# Flutter transparent button elevation

Tags: flutter

I created a custom button that I want to give a color and an elevation. Works finde, except when I give the button the color `Colors.transparent`. Here is an example to showcase my problem:

```
Widget buildButton(void Function() onPressed, String label, double? elevation) {
  return OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: Text(label),
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        side: BorderSide(
          width: 2,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        elevation: elevation ?? 0
    ),
  );
}

class ButtonsDemo extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            buildButton(() {}, "Button", null),
            buildButton(() {}, "Button", 5),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The buttons look like this:

[image]

Here is how they should look like (I set the color of the buttons to the background color of the screen to showcase them, but I can't do that in my code):

[image]

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458009/flutter-how-to-add-shadow-to-transparent-container/64470100#64470100) but it only got me so far (I don't know if I did it completely wrong, but it looks so):

[image]

I also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155475/transparent-card-but-with-shadow-effect-from-elevation/66155729#66155729) and it got me there:

[image]

So, as you can see, both of them answers haven't helped me at all. Can anyone show me how I can add elevation to a transparent button?

Comment: Do you really need transparent background? The button you show can also be white background, is that ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Elevated and Not Elevated]

The best solution to your problem is to use `ElevatedButton` instead of `OutlinedButton` and to give it a `shadowColor`. The code below is for the second button, please give it a try.

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'Elevated',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            elevation: 5,
            primary: Colors.transparent,
            shadowColor: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.1),
            side: BorderSide(
              width: 2,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: This does not solve @Apri's answer. The shadow of the button will still be visible under the button itself when setting it's primary to transparent